# Top-down game camera movement

Tags: actionscript-3, camera, 2d-games, starling-framework

I'm developing a top-down view game, and I've got a problem with the camera.
Currently camera simply follows the player entity - it seems fine to me, but people want another camera.
I'm using Starling, and StarlingPunk, but it shouldn't make much difference, its more theoretical question.

Camera works like this:

```
public function centerOnEntity(target:SPEntity):void
{
    var newCameraX:Number = (target.x + target.width / 2) - SP.width / 2;
    var newCameraY:Number = (target.y + target.height / 2) - SP.height / 2;
    SP.camera.setPosition(newCameraX, newCameraY);
}
```

And basically, every frame, camera is centered on the user.
Following image will demonstrate the problem:
[image: Camera movement]

As you can see, I've got rectangular levels, and if level is small, or user is near to the level bounds a background image is displayed.

So, what kind of camera do I need?
I need a camera, that will show maximum level space, and minimum background image.

How can I achieve that?
Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could just put an offset to the camera x and y coordinates if you are near any border. Easiest solution would be to make sure the possible values for the coordinates are bounded. For example `newCameraX = Math.min(Math.max(leftLimit, newCameraX), rightLimit)`

Comment: Thank you, will give it a try right now!

Comment: That did the job! Thank you very much! I had to use (a<b) ? a : b; instead of Math.min and (a>b) ? a: b; instead of Math.max, due to performance problems, cause this function runs every frame, but it works!